# Need help rethinking my timeline concept

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timeline

I've created a little page where you can drag and drop an audio file, which then will be uploaded. Then a waveform is being created and the bpm (beats per minute) of the audio ar being calculated. Up to here: no problem.

Then I create a (kind of) horizontal timeline, where a part of the waveform is being displayed, which will scroll if you play the audio. On the waveform "beat-markers" are being drawn. They indicate each "beat". I think you know what I mean. Then there is a "grid" on the beat-markers which allows to draw up to four "notes" in every beat - up to three notes "one above the other". To be a little musical: If a beat is a 1/4 note every drawn note would be 1/16 note. If you're a little confused right now, just watch the short video below and I'm pretty sure all of your ambiguities will vanish.
So that's the concept...
Here's a little demo-video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkT4LcSAcvo

Now my implementation for creating the grid:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createBeatBoxes() {
        var duration = audio.duration;
        var measures = Math.floor((duration/(60/bpm))/beatPerMeasure); //calculate the amount of measures for the complete song - beatsPerMeasure defines time signature (eg. 4/4 or 3/4)
        var gapPixel = gap*secondWidth; //secondWidth defines how wide will be one second on the timeline (eg. "secondWidth=20" would mean the timeline of a song which is 10 seconds long would be 20*10 = 200 pixels wide)
        var measurePixel = secondWidth*(60/bpm)*beatPerMeasure; /defines the width of of one measure
        var beatPixel = measurePixel/beatPerMeasure; /defines the width of one beat
        var notePixel = beatPixel/notesPerBeat; /defines the width of one note - notesPerBeat defines the amount of notes in one beat
        for (i=1;i <= measures;i++) {

            var measureBox = document.createElement("div");
            measureBox.setAttribute('class', 'measureBox');
            if (i == 1) {
                measureBox.setAttribute('style', 'left:'+gapPixel+'px;width:'+measurePixel+'px');
            }
            else {
                measureBox.setAttribute('style', 'left:'+(((i-1)*measurePixel)+gapPixel)+'px;width:'+measurePixel+'px');
            }
            for (j=1;j <= beatPerMeasure;j++) {
                var beatBox = document.createElement("div");
                 beatBox.setAttribute('class', 'beatBox');
                beatBox.setAttribute('style', 'left:'+((j-1)*beatPixel)+'px;width:'+beatPixel+'px');
                for (k=1;k <= notesPerBeat;k++) {
                    var noteBarBox = document.createElement("div");
                    noteBarBox.setAttribute('class', 'noteBarBox');
                    noteBarBox.setAttribute('style', 'left:-'+(0.5*notePixel)+'px;width:'+notePixel+'px');
                        var noteBox = document.createElement("div");
                        noteBox.setAttribute('class', 'noteBox rednoteBox');
                        noteBox.setAttribute('onClick', 'toogleNote(this,"red")');
                        noteBarBox.appendChild(noteBox);
                        var noteBox = document.createElement("div");
                        noteBox.setAttribute('class', 'noteBox greennoteBox');
                        noteBox.setAttribute('onClick', 'toogleNote(this,"green")');
                        noteBarBox.appendChild(noteBox); 
                        var noteBox = document.createElement("div");
                        noteBox.setAttribute('class', 'noteBox bluenoteBox');
                        noteBox.setAttribute('onClick', 'toogleNote(this,"blue")');
                        noteBarBox.appendChild(noteBox); 
                    beatBox.appendChild(noteBarBox);
                }
                measureBox.appendChild(beatBox); 
            }
            document.querySelector('#timeline').appendChild(measureBox); 


        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem with this implementation is that the timeline itself is a very wide div (eg. 950000px) containing an img with the drawn waveform. In that div there are many measures divs which contain (4) beat-divs which again contain (4) note-divs with 3 different note-sub-divs. Here's a little extract:

```
<div class="measureBox" style="left:1.746031745px;width:975.609756097561px">
    <div class="beatBox" style="left:0px;width:242.65243902439025px">
        <div class="noteBarBox" style="left:-29.964304878048782px;width:59.928609756097565px">
            <div class="noteBox rednoteBox" onclick="toogleNote(this,&quot;red&quot;)"></div>
            <div class="noteBox greennoteBox" onclick="toogleNote(this,&quot;green&quot;)"></div>
            <div class="noteBox bluenoteBox" onclick="toogleNote(this,&quot;blue&quot;)"></div>
            ...
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

This is the css:

```
.measureBox {
    height:400px;
    float:left;
    border-right: 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    position:absolute;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    top:0;
}
.beatBox {
    height:400px;
    float:left;
    border-right: 3px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.noteBarBox {
    position: relative;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.noteBox {
    float:left;
    height:133.33px;
    width:inherit;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border-radius: 66.66px;
}
.redNoteBox { 
    top:0;
}
.greenNoteBox { 
    top:133.33px;
}
.blueNoteBox { 
    top:266.66px;
}
```

Summing up all divs they have a length of over 300.000 characters which of course can't be scrolled smooth anymore and the cpu is completely overwhelmed.

Is there maybe any other way to create these "beat-markers" and the possibility to "draw" notes on a grid at specific gaps/distances which doesn't need so much processor load?

I hope you come up with some good ideas or even a bit of code. That would be awesome, because I completely stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<canvas>`, and draw only the elements which should actually be visible at a given time.

Comment: Thank you, for your quick reply! :) This sounds quite logic! Can you give me an example of how to draw html-tags on canvas? I have absolutely no idea...

Comment: Find yourself some documentation and/or a tutorial. It's a big topic.